# How to get separate RDD for each key entry

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, java-8, rdd

I'm playing around with `JavaPariRDD`. I have a pairRDD which has *APL,IBM* as **Key** and its trading transactions as **values**. Something like this (Dummy data provided here)

> (NYSE IBM 2001-12-27  122.7   123.93  122.64  123.5   3826200 111.65)
>
> (NYSE APL 2001-12-27  12.75   12.93   12.64   12.5    3826200 11.65)

Now I have a scenario where I need to have separate RDD for each key. My immediate option is `filter()`

```
sBookRdd = sourceRDD.filter(new MyFilter("IBM")); 
sBookRdd = sourceRDD.filter(new MyFilter("APL"));
```

If I have seperate RDD for each company/StockName,I can perform company specific analysis and what not.
My question here is, is their any other better approach for my scenario?

Comment: If you could tell the requirement clearly, people will be able to suggest a better scenario. Why to you want many RDDs? What you want to do with the RDDs that you cannot do with the single RDD?

Comment: Updated my question.@rakesh

Answer (score 1):

Spark doesn't support RDD nesting so there is no simple way to break an RDD into many RDDs without intermediate actions. The approach you should take depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you absolutely require an RDD for each key then you can repartition the data, write it such that the files for each partition are easy to identify and then kick off multiple jobs to deal with each partition. I would not recommend this approach.

If you can get away with an `Iterable` then you can use `groupBy` or its more efficient cousin `aggregate`. With only strings as the values, it's hard to imagine why an iterable would not serve your needs and an RDD is required...

You should also consider whether what you need to do can be accomplished with the dataframe/dataset API using window functions (where you will partition by the key).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Checking with aggregate as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

RDD is the core abstraction in spark for encapsulating a data that is distributed (most likely across machines). Though it supports many of the list/iterable methods, using an RDD as an iterable/list is wrong.

Note: Any transformation on an RDD is lazy and any action on RDD will be executed in parallel by the executors (could be in same/different jvms&&or||machines).

With this fact in mind, now if the requirement is to process all records with same key (lets say "NYSE IBM") at a time, you will have to do something as below, I am writing in scala, you could find the java equivalent -

```
val input = Array("NYSE IBM 2001-12-27 122.7 123.93 122.64 123.5 3826200 111.65", "NYSE APL 2001-12-27 12.75 12.93 12.64 12.5 3826200 11.65")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(input)
val groupedRdd = rdd.groupBy(line => methodWhichReturnsKeyFromEachLine(line))
groupedRdd.foreach(group=>processGroup(group)) //If you want to process all lines in a group without returning any result
groupedRdd.map(group=>processGroup(group)) //If you want to process all lines in a group and return some result per group
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: GroupBy() is not my option since its shuffles data.

Comment: You mean, you are not allowed to use any operation that does a shuffle!!! That seems a big restriction while using spark. Any particular reason?

Comment: aggregatebyKey() seems to be suitable to me as mentioned by @Sim